# Back to Top Button is not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, button

HTML code

```
<div id="toTop" class="active">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
/* Styling of back to top arrow button */
#toTop {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 32px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #093;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none; */
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

JS code

```
// Adding functioning of back to top button
const toTop = document.getElementById('toTop');

toTop.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  
  console.log('pressed');
});
```

This back to top arrow button is not show functioning in my website.
Even `pressed` is comes in the console on every click but page is not comes to the head of the website.

In console, there are so many errors of related to tailwind css.

Comment: with only very small part of your code, not easy to answer! Are you sure it's document (window) which has the scroll, not an inside div? Can you try just window.scroll(0,0), without the behavior?

Comment: Please put a snippet of your code (HTML and JS) in order to understand better your issue. An online sandbox (such as codepen or stackblitz) would even better for us to debug

Comment: it works on my computer, you can try to use this: `<div id="toTop" class="active">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up">To top</i>
</div>`